# retrieve specific data from particular column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data to **compliance table** , theres column named **auditee** which is not a primary key.

So after data entry. I want to retrieve the data according to "auditee"

Should I insert data into multiple tables in MySQL (compliance table & auditee_details table) or any ideas?

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mtt_iem");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$a = $_POST['date'];
$b = $_POST['block'];
$c = $_POST['module'];
$d = $_POST['auditor'];
$e = $_POST['sw_score'];
$f = $_POST['sw_comment'];
$g = $_POST['dm_score'];
$h = $_POST['dm_comment'];
$i = $_POST['uniform_score'];
$j = $_POST['uniform_comment'];
$k = $_POST['totalscore'];
$l = $_POST['auditorcomment'];
$m = $_POST['auditee'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO compliance_module 



(date,block,module,auditor,sw_score,sw_comment,dm_score,dm_comment,uniform_score,uniform_comment,totalscore,auditorcomment,auditee) ".

"VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$h','$i','$j','$k','$l','$m')";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: seems like all your asking for is: `select * from compliance_module WHERE auditee='foo' `

Comment: You need to use mysqli_escape to escape your data values (or better yet use parameterized queries). Otherwise people can post SQL to your form and steal your data/wreck your database. Also, the use of $a, $b, $c, etc. is unnecessary and just makes your code confusing and lengthy. You could use $_POST[auditee] (no quotes around the auditee when you are using it in a string) right in the string if you wanted to (but don't, you need to escape it first).

Comment: @Enstage noted with thanks. I'll try to improve my coding. Will learn about SQL injection

Comment: @rtfm i tried sql with condition but seems like it cannot detect the specific auditee

Comment: @Cuagau Will try to improve my knowledge on this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store additional information about the auditee, and one auditee can have multiple compliance_modules, then you would want to create a separate auditee table with an auditee_id, and use an audite_id field on the compliance_modules table to reference which auditee_id you belong to.

If the table is going to have a lot of records, and you will be looking up modules by auditee, you will want to create an index on that value, which will make searches orders of magnitude quicker:

```
CREATE INDEX compliance_modules_auditee_id ON compliance_modules(auditee_id)
```

Then you can do

```
SELECT * FROM compliance_modules WHERE auditee_id = 'foo'
```

Comment: Yes, one auditee can have multiple compliance_modules. So in compliance_modules table, i need a auditee_id column? Not just the auditee? So the auditee_id in auditee table is a primary key right? @Cuagau